# Getting undefined outside function

Tags: javascript, dhtml

Hi I'm looking into some code for an admessage i, can get the values i want and run trough them BUT, when I try to use these "outside" the function or update variable outside it come out as undefined here is the setup

HTML page with script tag for my javascript file (tested works) 
The Javascript is as follows:

```
dhtml.adMessage.getPage(dhtml.getVar('rotseqno', 1), function (err, items, info){

    if (err) {
        // Handle AdMessage service error
        dhtml.addClass(dhtml.byId('wrapper'), 'error');
        dhtml.byId('wrapper').innerHTML = err.message;
    }
    else {

        console.log(Object.keys(items).length); //works --> 1
        adDataStr = JSON.stringify(items); //works 
        console.log(adDataStr); // -> String comes out with correct content
        console.log(typeof(adDataStr)); //--> string
        //setAdData(adDataStr); //Does not work undefined
        //dataarray = adDataStr; //Does not work undefined          
        }
});
```

I suspect it has something to do with when things are run. as the console.logs from inside function in code seems to come last. on debugger (chrome) and where I try getting value from html page comes first as undefined.
Have been looking around alot but can't seem to find just the right solution.
Is there anyone that can point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: We need to see the code that defines `setAdData` as it is that which is undefined

Comment: I guess `getPage` is asynchronous. You can't use the variables outside the function if data hasn't loaded yet.

Comment: setAdaData was just at setter I tried to update data outside the dhtml.adMessage.getPage... was like this: function setAdData(str){ dataarray = str;}

Comment: Andy: how do i make sure it is run and get data before i call from HTML side, I've been looking at callback but can't seem to get my head around it.